# Backbone.js datepicker event listener without a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, datepicker

I am new to backbone and I'm trying to create a datepicker. I am trying to add an event listener without a model but the click event listener i added in the view is acting funny so I assume I'm going about this wrong.  The code I'm trying to emulate (which works) is as follows:

```
initialize:function () {
    ...
    this.model.bind('change', this.pageSetup, this);
    ...
}

  pageSetup:function () {

    var self = this;

      $("#date-range").datepicker({
        onSelect:function (dateText, datePickeOBJ) {
          self.selectedDate = dateText;
          self.onDateChange(datePickeOBJ);
        },
        defaultDate: this.selectedDate,
        maxDate:'-2'
      });
    ...
 }
```

which seems to work fine.  In my case there is no model.  Right now I have

```
return BaseView.extend({
  el: "<div id='main-inner'>",

  template: "print-report",
  events: {
      "change #date-range": "datePicker"
  }, ...
datePicker: function() {
 var self = this;

$("#date-range").datepicker({
        onSelect:function (dateText, datePickeOBJ) {
          self.selectedDate = dateText;
          self.onDateChange(datePickeOBJ);
        },
        defaultDate: this.selectedDate,
        maxDate:'-2'
      });
 }, ...
```

How could I better go about this is good backbone fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just create the `$.datepicker()` on `mouseover`.

```
events: {
  'mouseover #dateinput' : 'createDatePicker'
},

createDatePicker:function(e) {
  var view = this;

  $(e.currentTarget).datepicker({
    maxDate:'-2',
    defaultDate:view.selectedDate,
    onSelect:function(dateText,datePicker) {
      console.log('onSelect',dateText);
      view.selectedDate = dateText;
      view.onDateChange(datePicker);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/sumedigapo/1/edit)